# How can I run through all the characters of a string and check if they're all numbers in C?

Tags: c, string, function, numbers, c-strings

I'm trying to find out a way to check all the characters of a string. After searching the web I found that I can create a function to do it but for some reason it doesn't work, even if it's pretty simple. Here is the code I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct id{
    char id_num[10];
};

int isNumber(char p[])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<strlen(p); i++){
        if(isdigit(p[i])){
            return 0;
        }
        else return 1;
    }
}


void read(struct id s)
{
    int len1;
    do{ 
        printf("Give id number: ");
        scanf("%s", s.id_num);
        len1 = strlen(s.id_num);
    } while(len1 < 0 || len1 > 10 || isNumber(s.id_num) == 1);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct id a;
    read(a);
}
```

In case you're wondering why I make the id_num a char string is because I need the number to be from 0 to 10 characters. 
Also, the code doesn't come up with any errors but it takes anything I input. For example it accepts "5555tt" when it shouldn't. What have I done wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should learn how to use a debugger and step through your program line by line.

Comment: Your function tests only the first character of the string, the loop notwithstanding, because the function returns after one character whether it is a digit or not.

Comment: `read()` is really a bad function name. There is a widely used POSIX function called `read()`.

Answer (score 3):

For starters the function `read` shall accept its argument by reference like

```
void read(struct id *s);
```

Otherwise its argument does not make sense.

Pay attention to that such a call of `scanf`

```
scanf("%s", s.id_num);
```

is unsafe. Use instead `fgets`. Fro example

```
void read( struct id *s )
{
    //...
    fgets( s->id_num, sizeof( s->id_num ), stdin );
    s->id_num[strcspn( s->id_num, "\n" )] = '\0';
```

The function `isNumber` is cery simple.

```
int isNumber( const char p[] ) 
{
    const char *s = p;
    while ( isdigit( ( unsigned char )*s ) ) ++s;

    return  p[0] != '\0' && *s == '\0';
}
```

That is the passed string shall not be empty (the condition `p[0] != '\0'` ). Otherwise it is evident that it does not contain all digits.

The second condition `*s == '\0'` means that we checked all characters of the string until the terminating zero. That is the string contains only digits.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int isNumber( const char p[] ) 
{
    const char *s = p;
    while ( isdigit( ( unsigned char )*s ) ) ++s;

    return  p[0] != '\0' && *s == '\0';
}

int main(void) 
{
    printf( "Is a number - %s\n", isNumber( "" ) ? "true" : "false"  );
    printf( "Is a number - %s\n", isNumber( "A" ) ? "true" : "false"  );
    printf( "Is a number - %s\n", isNumber( "12A" ) ? "true" : "false"  );
    printf( "Is a number - %s\n", isNumber( "123" ) ? "true" : "false"  );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
Is a number - false
Is a number - false
Is a number - false
Is a number - true
```

Comment: Wow it works, but it doesn't work when I make the first change you said (making it void read(struct id *s). Can you explain to me how you came up with the function you wrote because I didn't really understand it I just copied it haha! Thanks!

Comment: Your `isNumber` code is typically (for you) brilliant, @Vlad! But maybe a little explanation for us lesser mortals?

Comment: @ThanosMitropoulos See my updated post. You have to use another member access operator with the pointer to structure.

Comment: Why do you set const char *s = p?  I actually don't understand your isNumber function at all! :D

Comment: @ThanosMitropoulos  I am using a copy of the parameter that to check after the while loop whether the original string was empty.

Comment: @ryyker I thought that it is a more expressive.:) Though it can be written for example like *p != '\0' && *s == '\0' or some other way.

Comment: @ThanosMitropoulos - The loop ( `while ( isdigit( ( unsigned char )*s ) ) ++s;` ) is sequencing though each character, testing that each is a digit. The loop will break on two conditions: 1) found non-digit. 2) reached end of string.  The `return` statement ( `return  p[0] != '\0' && *s == '\0';` ) is simply a logical statement with two conditions being tested: 1) the input parameter was not `null` to begin with (which could have been tested at the beginning of the function.) 2) that the loop reached the string's `null` terminator, indicating there were no non-digits in the string...

Comment: @ThanosMitropoulos -  ... If both conditions are true the function returns a 1, if either is false, function returns a 0.

Comment: @AdrianMole - Regarding your comment, see the 2 comments above.

Comment: @ryyker Vlad's edit was what I was looking for! It earned him a hard-fought "+10" from me! ‎

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop, you exit when you find a digit. So if the first char is `5` then you exit the loop.  What you need is to check all elements and return with `1` if not a digit.

```
int isNumber(char p[])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<strlen(p); i++){
        if(!isdigit(p[i])){
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also the function `read` needs to take the parameter by address. `void read(struct id *s)`

```
void read(struct id *s)
{
    int len1;
    do{ 
        printf("Give id number: ");
        scanf("%s", s->id_num);
        len1 = strlen(s->id_num);
    } while((len1 < 0) || (len1 > 10) || (isNumber(s->id_num) == 1));
}
```

Comment: I think you should return `0` on `if(!isdigit())…` and you ***must*** scrap the `else return 0;` and just have `return 1` ***after*** the loop.

Comment: In the `while` loop the condition checked is `isNumber(s.id_num) == 1` to continue the loop and read again. So returned as shown.

Comment: Your modified `isNumber` will always return after checking the first character. Remove `else return 0;` and add `return 0;` at the end of the function.

Comment: @AdrianMole Function `read` in the question seems to assume that return value `1` indicates invalid input. (This does not correspond to the normal convention of TRUE/FALSE.)

Comment: I don't see the difference really. You just added an exclamation mark before isdigit and changed the 0 and 1?

Comment: @Bodo OK - I'll accept that the OP wants the 'unconventional' response! (And the loop issue has now been fixed, so I'm done.)